# C++ code that compiles as managed .NET in visual studio (C++/CLI) and as native C++ otherwise

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, g++, c++-cli

I have a C++ library that compiles on Linux and would like to compile the same code in Visual Studio (.NET compatible code).

I have successfully compiled the same native code in Visual Studio (no graphics involved). However, I would like to expose some class to .NET. I could write a managed wrapper to some unmanaged class - if I spend the time which I do not really have. However, for some simple classes it seems that using the directive at the beginning

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    public ref class myclass
#else
    class myclass
#endif
```

can do the trick. The code compiles as managed in visual studio and as native otherwise. However, some classes involving pointers return errors at compilation time. I know that "*" is the unmanaged pointer and "^" the managed pointer. Can I just define

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define POINTER ^
#else
    #define POINTER *
#endif
```

This is research code that gets modified quite often. Writing a wrapper would be time consuming and would also require to modify the wrapper every time the native class is modified. I would therefore prefer to use conditional statements as the one above (but I would like to use as few as possible). Is there a tutorial for writing code that is maximally compatible between native C++ and C++/CLI.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be aware you have no GC!!

Comment: Or the other way - native C++ is not expecting GC

Comment: Don't use naked pointers when compiling in native C++. You have a chance at success with refcounted smart pointers (be careful of cycles though).

Answer (score 0):

The C++/CLI ref pointer is not the same as * pointer.  There is no 1 for 1 equivalence.  The ref ^ pointer refers to objects that are "reference types" (as opposed to "value types") as defined in the CLR, and they are can be instantiated with gcnew.  Gcnew is very important because it tells the marshaller that the object to be created is under garbage collection, and so these types do not work with native code, they need to be marshaled.  BUT, in order to actually pass something by reference, e.g. to be able to write back to a parameter passed in a function, you need to also use % ... so Form ^ myForm, if being passed in order to get a return value needs to be written Form ^ %myForm.

The best thing for you to do is to write a wrapper and use a mixed assembly paradigm.

I am not sure coming from Linux C++ code, but to do this from the word go in Windows, you would create a MFC C++ library (or executable) and then manually turn on the Common Language Runtime and manually add a AssemblyInfo.cpp and app.manifest file to the project.

From there, within your code, there is a #pragma for defining which sections of code are which.

For code that runs native, or outside of managed context, you would want to write:

```
#pragma unmanaged
```

which tells the compile to treat everything thereafter as unmanaged code.

To turn managed code back on for a section of code within the same file:

```
#pragma managed
```

and so on, and so forth.

It does appear to be the case that you might have to write a wrapper.  It doesn't have to be a complete wrapper ... perhaps just an entry point to return the end result of whatever it is you're trying to do ... and any unique programming that needs to be done, should be done in a mixed assembly binary, which the .NET types exposed only for the most objective-oriented tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended defining a header file that allows me to compile either in managed (under Visual Studio) or unmanaged mode.

The other change I had to make is to remove all object instances in class definition. For example, I have to change all "string" objects to pointers "string *" (then also change declaration assignment etc...) so it would compile both as unmanaged and managed code.

```
#ifndef COMMONHEADER_H_
#define COMMONHEADER_H_

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define CLASS public ref class
#define POINTER ^
#define NEW gcnew
#define ARRAY(A, B) array<A ^> ^ B
#define VECTOR(A, B) array<A> ^ B
#define NEWARRAY(A, SIZE) gcnew array<A ^>(SIZE)
#define NULLPTR nullptr
#else
#define CLASS class
#define POINTER *
#define NEW new
#define ARRAY(A, B) A * * B
#define VECTOR(A, B) vector<A> * B
#define NEWARRAY(A, SIZE) new A*[SIZE];
#define NULLPTR NULL
#endif

#endif /* COMMONHEADER_H_ */
```

Then I went on to use these in my class definition. I replaced all objects pointers "*" by POINTER and all instances of "new" by "NEW", etc...

```
CLASS myclass
{
public:
    MyObject POINTER obj1;
    ARRAY(MyObject, objArray);
...
```

In some cases, I also had to write a wrapper for some of my functions. For example, below to overload a function that takes a managed string and pass it to the function that takes the unmanaged string as input.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
bool saveToTxtFile(array<unsigned char>^ file) { pin_ptr<unsigned char> tmp = &file[0]; return saveToTxtFile((char *)tmp); }
#endif
```

Or below to return an unmanaged data array as a managed data array.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
array<double> ^ getValues() {
     array<double> ^tmpArray = gcnew array<double>(numberOfSamples);
     for (int ind1 = 0; ind1 < numberOfSamples; ind1++) tmpArray[ind1] = data[ind1];
     return tmpArray;
}
#endif
```

I am aware that writing a full wrapper is more elegant and probably more robust in the long run than using this trick. However, I have about 2000 lines of code and it saved me a lot of time not to have to write wrappers for my 30 objects. Also, this way, I do not have to maintain the wrappers in case I change the class and I do not need to double the number of classes. The final advantage is that when my code is compiled as managed code, all of my objects are handled by the garbage collector.

So, to sum up, it is not the most elegant solution, but it is possible and it works.